# Rails Global Function: Pass Object Function Is Called On

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a global function, which I will put in my application controller.

For the sake of making this question simple, here is an example of what I would do:

In my `/application_controller.rb`

```
def self.global_function(device)
    p device
end
```

And in the controller I'm working in:

```
def some_function
  global_function(Device.find(some_id))
end
```

That works, but I would like to have it work, for example, as the `.last` method does. The end result would allow me to call like this instead:

```
def some_function
    Device.find(some_id).global_function
end
```

Still passing the device object over, but without the need for parameters.

I can't give a reason for why I prefer one over the other, aside from aesthetics. If there are any drawbacks from using one way over the other, I'd like to know that as well. Thanks

Comment: For the record, I did research this issue before posting. Not sure why people feel it's ok to downvote without giving a reason. If it was a duplicate, at least provide a link to the original and vote to close.

Comment: You *may* be looking for helpers.  They're cleaner and don't require too much thinking about, but the first form would likely be what you have to use, since the second form implies you have some kind of method glommed into your Active Record objects, which doesn't feel quite *right*.

Comment: Downvotes indicate a question is "unclear or not useful", and your question really isn't. You've misused the words "global" and "function", what you're describing has nothing to do with either of those terms, so this question is not useful to anybody else. People arriving here from Google because they're searching for "global functions in Rails" will find absolutely nothing relevant in your question or the answers it generates.

Comment: @meager Thanks for a response. I mentioned in a comment that I did indeed confuse the 2. That being said, I feel I made pretty clear what I was trying to accomplish. Instead of down voting, perhaps one could suggest an edit to make the posting more "clear and useful".

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about what is a *function* vs what is a *method*.

This has nothing to do with making a "global function". You just need to define a plain old method on `Device`:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_method
    # do something with `self`
  end
end
```

This will let you invoke `global_method` on any `Device` instance, such as the one returned by `find`:

```
Device.find(some_id).some_method
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First, I thought I might be confusing the 2. Second, I understand how to do this. I need it global, so I can call in any controller and on any model. Just like the `.last` method.

Comment: Then you need to define a method on `ActiveRecord::Base` (in old Rails) or on `ApplicationRecord` (in Rails 5+), or make your method available in a concern and add that concern to your models. This is still a misuse of the word ["global"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).

Comment: @meager Thanks for the info. I'll start looking into those. I now feel this may be appropriate to close as not useful.